# Customizing Ajax Toolkit Html Editor Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Two questions:

1: my requirement is absolutely weird. To add a dropdown in the existing toolbar of HTMLEditor of Ajaxtoolkit and that dropdown will be populated from the database.
I am stucked with the issue .. please help me out.

Or if its not possible

2:  any way to display context menu inside the HTML editor and from context menu , i can choose item, and that item will get placed at the position from where context menu is called. Also that context menu will be able to display data from database. I hope you can under stand , first one is my issue and another one is its workaround.....

Any one would be a great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but it could be quite a complex task.  There are several ways to approach it:

1. Create a new class/script file that inherits from both the server and client side component.  This would probably be not as practical as #2 would be as of how it may have been designed.
2. Get the source code from the ACT, available online at codeplex.com or from the asp.net web site, and modify the source directly to add your needs.  It will make upgrading harder, but would be easier to implement the feature you want.
3. Look for another online solution.

HTH.